# Disable RecyclerView scrolling, so scrollview CHILD can scroll

Tags: android, uiscrollview, scrollview, android-recyclerview

### **ScrollView inside RecyclerView**

Childs are inserted by the adapter, the recycler is sectioned, third child is a scrollview, but it must scroll just in the space left after first and second childs are placed.

I need to disable recyclerview scrolling without disabling scrollview's

Recycler container

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Lightgrey"
tools:context="com.inhousecrew.nocturnalkey.fragments.NightDetailsFragment">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/nightlife_detailsrecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:background="@color/Background"
            />


</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the XML initial attr for scrollview container (recyclerview's third child)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="220dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/scroll_details"
android:background="@color/Lightgrey">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="false">

</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally this is the java class containing the recycler, for logic purposes I'm using a adapter to change data in first child, that's why I'm using a recyclerview (in the first place)

```
public class NightDetailsFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView mRecyclerNight;
private NightDetailsAdapter mAdapter;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;



public static NightlifeFragment newInstance() {
    NightlifeFragment fragment = new NightlifeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

public NightDetailsFragment() {

}

public List<Information> getData() {
    //load only static data inside a drawer
    List<com.inhousecrew.nocturnalkey.fragments.Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int icons = R.drawable.settings_w;
    String titles = "Settings";
    int background = R.drawable.background_user;


        com.inhousecrew.nocturnalkey.fragments.Information information = new com.inhousecrew.nocturnalkey.fragments.Information();
        information.title = titles;
        information.iconId = icons;
        information.backgroundId = background;
        if(titles.equals("Profile")){
            information.nightlife_active = getResources().getColor(R.color.inactive_event);
        }else{
            information.nightlife_active = getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow);
        }

        data.add(information);


    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_night_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRecyclerNight = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.nightlife_detailsrecycler);
    mAdapter = new NightDetailsAdapter(getActivity() ,getData());

    mRecyclerNight.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerNight.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

}



public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

}
```

Comment: If you want the first two items to be fixed in size and not scroll with the remainder (to ensure the remaining items only take up the space remaining), why are they even in the `RecyclerView` instead of as fixed elements above a `RecyclerView`?

Comment: because when I set the layout containing the recycler, it only shows the recycler even if a set the heigh at shorter than the size of the screen (vertically), it just ignores all the views except for recycler

Comment: That's a totally different problem: post your layout file that is showing the problem and maybe we can help you with the underlying problem

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass RecyclerView and override onMeasure like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
    getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
}
```